# How to iterate over ExpandableListView children?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I need to iterate through ExpandableListView children on childClick and change childView.
How can I do that? After changing childView should I notify adapter?

```
    // Adapter
    FinancesExpListViewAdapter adapter = new FinancesExpListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), groups, moneyAdapter);

    // ExpandableListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getGroupCount();i++) {

                    for(int k = 0; k < adapter.getChildrenCount(i); k++) {
                     //to do here
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You shouldn't iterate and modify them like that. If you want to modify the views do it in the adapter. Remember that the views are re-used whenever the list is scrolled. If you want an easy solution, you should probably re-think your design.